# Re-factoring Controller's Action  in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, refactoring

I am writing this Action code (within same controller) more than 10 times for different `Models`. Is there any way i can reduce this code or how can i create a generic action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SavePerson(Person p)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
            return Redirect("/Main");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCategory(Category c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
            return Redirect("/Main");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The main point is that `//do something` part always differs from action to action. So let's try to reduce all code other than that. You could use base controller for it

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [NonAction]
    protected virtual ActionResult HandlePost<T>(T model, Action<T> processValidModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            processValidModel(model);
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

And in derived controller

```
public class DerivedController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
       return HandlePost(person, p => _repository.Save(p));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ModelState.IsValid ? Redirect("/Main"):View();
```

as a start point would be the only line you need.

Comment: but i have to create multiple actions.

Comment: yep, i just briefly broke down what you have in each one, I'm not that versed on mvc3, so with the Actions and so on - not too sure, but trimming down the code you need so hopefully someone can help you with the action stuff and you can trim down the whole thing with that...

Answer (score -2):

For functions which are going to be called too often, create a static class and define all such functions in that.

for example like following

```
public static class MyAppStaticClass
{
    public static SavePerson(Person p)
    {
        ... // your body
    }
}
```

Then, you can refer it like `MyAppStaticClass.SavePerson` whenever you need it.

Comment: ohhh k....you mean to say you want some refactoring for if (ModelState.IsValid) and redirect/return statement.....sorry, i thought you were looking for the refactoring of `//do something`